# presence of turbulent phenomena in systems of linear pde?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Are there linear systems of PDE that are known to have solutions which exhibit turbulence, or can turbulence be firmly classified as a fundamentally non-linear phenomenon, similar to solitons or shock development? Relatedly, can you see turbulent behavior in solutions to linear approximations of any of the non-linear PDE which are known to behave turbulently in some cases?

Since turbulence is difficult to define rigorously and remains poorly understood mathematically, I will simply use the term to refer to the heuristic phenomena identified as such. I refer to the phenomenon as it is seen in Navier-Stokes and other equations modeling fluid dynamics. I am interested in numerical and theoretical results.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory#Minimum_complexity_of_a_chaotic_system

Comment: Can you give an example or a link to what you mean by "as it is seen in Navier-Stokes or other equations modeling fluid dynamics"? You also tagged this question "hyperbolic-pde": do you really want to be that restrictive?